# Generating PDF with dynamic image from storage stalls in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, mpdf

I have an issue with a view and generated content to produce a PDF. At the moment, I've been working with niklasravnsborg\LaravelPdf (a wrapper for mPDF, because of an issue with another PDF writer I was working with beforehand), which turns out nice PDFs that are of the quality that I want.

I have never had an issue with images inside of the view before with this PDF writer though, but I must admit that they were with images that had been set-up inside the view already (like a logo, rather than say an employees photo).

My issue arises in a way that has at least allowed me to track down the issue a little better.

From my controller, I get the following:

`$employeeMedCert = $employee->attachments()->where('category','Medical Examiners Certificate')->orderBy('endDate','desc')->limit(1)->get();`

And then in my blade I have the following:

```
@foreach($employeeMedCert as $med){
    {{Storage::url($med->attachment)}}
 @endforeach
```

Now, with this current setup, I get the public path of the attachment, without any issue at all.

*However*, if I do the following:

```
@foreach($employeeMedCert as $med){
    <img src="{{Storage::url($med->attachment)}}">
@endforeach
```

It stalls my Laravel to a point where I have to reset the server and hasn't generated anything.

I'm not sure what the issue is, like I said, I've had no issues with images before and the images I am referencing dynamically aren't large by any means (300 - 600 kB), so I am not sure where the issue actually is.

Upload controller action:

```
        $path = Storage::putFile('public/employees', new File(request('file')));

        employeeAttachment::create([
                        'attachment' => $path,
                        'attachmentType' => Storage::mimeType($path),
                        'category' => $request->type,
                        'endDate' => $request->dueDate,
                        'date' => $request->date,
                        'employeeID' => $employee,
                        'createdBy' =>  Auth::id()
                    ]);
```

Comment: `@enforeach` should be `@endforeach`.  Could be causing your issue with a loop that isn't closed.

Comment: @hdifen - Unfortunately, that was just a typo on this post. It would have been nice if it were that though.

Comment: My assumption is that `Storage::url()` expects a single string and it appears you are passing in an object. Have you tried `{{Storage::url($med->attachment->url)}}`?

Comment: @hdifen - Please see my above changes at the bottom. Is that what you were referring to? Because unfortunately, that too resulted in an issue...

Comment: Your naming convention confused me a bit sorry so that won't be your issue. I'll have a think

Comment: Are your files public?

Comment: @hdifen - Yes, I use this specific attachment in a couple other places within my project without any permissions/paths errors.

Comment: Another reminder, Matthew, that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0):

The big clue for this problem is that in html `<img>` tags do a get request when they are run in html.  This means you could be having a permission error.

You can check this by opening your devtools in chrome and checking out your server requests in any website that has an image tag.

Following things to check (assuming you are using a basic storage e.g. not using AWS):

1. Is image in your public folder or have you correctly created your sym link: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem.
2. If your files are public can you navigate to it in the browser?
3. Have you tried using the url instead of going through storage? e.g. `<img src="{{base_url() . $med->attachment)}}">` (assuming `$med->attachment` is a file path).

Assuming it's a public file you shouldn't have to go through the `Storage` facade to access it. Let me know if this points you in the right direction.

The purpose of the `Storage` facade is to save files and get files and load them into a php variable. Currently you are loading the file from the server and then pointing your image tag to the file and not to the url of where the image is stored.

Putting in a valid url into the `img` tag should solve your problem (shown in 3 above).

Comment: I've got all but number 3. My problem (and maybe you might be able to guide me in the right direction is that at the moment, the attachment path that is returned (just through $med->attachment) is "public/employees/lAwWqHfur0aLx071KRdaxEyhx4Hh60ktjziUBklk.jpeg" - this is a problem because for it to be found, it needs to have the url "/storage/employees/...."

Comment: Are you rewriting your url in `.htaccess` to not have 'public'?

Comment: I haven't touched that yet, but your comment made me wonder - I actually inherited this project and am trying to perform some much needed updated, at the moment, when a user uploads an attachment of some kind, this is the controller process below, would there be a better way of handling it in this particular case? (SEE ABOVE EDIT)

Comment: That seems fine.  Can you do go `dd(base_url() . $med->attachment);` and check if you can go to that url in the browser? You should see the image.

Comment: Where would you like me to put that in the controller so I can get the results you are looking for?

Comment: Yea in the controller would be best.  I think your problem is that the url that is being generate isn't correct.

Comment: I have go offline, I've updated my answer above to help get you on the right path. Let me know how you get on.

Comment: As an update, I have discovered it has to be something with the image tag itself. I had to alter your suggestion to refer to asset (to get the public url to get to the storage location). That had no problem at all, it gave me the full: http://192.168.1.178:8000/storage/employees/lAwWqHfur0aLx071KRdaxEyhx4Hh60ktjziUBklk.jpeg - which is the exact way to access the file, without any issues there. But when I put it in the <img src="(url here)">, is when it broke the PDF generator again.

Comment: Do you get the same bug?  Maybe try hard coding a file directly such as `<img src="/storage/employees/picture.jpg">`.

Comment: Yes, at this point I hard coded the full URL path into the blade template, the relative path into the template, but they continue to break the generator. I tried an external image and it loaded in the PDF in no time. So I'm really not sure what's going on at this point...